# <div> element isn't at top of it's <div> container

Tags: html, css, menu

I have a div element (innerBar) inside another one (leftBar), and unless I specify the innerBar's border to have some width, the innerBar isn't starting at the top of the leftBar.

How do  fix this?

```css
.leftBar {
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.innerBar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="leftBar">
  <div class="innerBar">
    <p>Some Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary to *position the nested element out of the document flow at all.*

This behaviour is a result of the default `margin` property declared on the nested `p` element (specifically the `margin-top` property), and can be rectified by either one of the following methods:

1. removing the `margin` property on the nested `p` tag:

   ```
   .innerBar p {
       margin-top: 0;
   }
   ```

   ```css
   * {
     box-sizing: border-box;
   }

   .leftBar {
     width: 10%;
     height: 100%;
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     border: 1px solid red;
   }

   .innerBar {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     background-color: lightblue;
     /* additional */
     display: inline-block;
     vertical-align: top;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="leftBar">
     <div class="innerBar">
       <p>Some Text</p>
     </div>
   </div>
   ```
2. declaring the following additional properties on the nested element
   (`innerBar`):

   ```
   .innerBar {
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
       background-color: lightblue;
       /* border: 1px solid yellow; */
       /* additional */
       display: inline-block;
       vertical-align: top;
   }
   ```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.leftBar {
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.innerBar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.innerBar p {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="leftBar">
  <div class="innerBar">
    <p>Some Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay got it, I just add to innerBar the property:

```
position: absolute;
```